# Shortening a for loop which pads first and last value of several lists

Tags: python

I have 3 lists (EIRP,data3,data15) and I'm looking for a way to shorten this code:

```
ws=3

for i in range(ws):
    EIRP.insert(0, EIRP[0])
    EIRP.append(EIRP[-1])
    data3.insert(0,data3[0])
    data3.append(data3[-1])
    data15.insert(0,data15[0])
    data15.append(data15[-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EIRP[0:0] = EIRP[:1] * 3
EIRP.extend(EIRP[-1:] * 3)

data3[0:0] = data3[:1] * 3
data3.extend(data3[-1:] * 3)

data15[0:0] = data15[:1] * 3
data15.extend(data15[-1:] * 3)
```

even shorter

```
EIRP = EIRP[:1] * 3 + EIRP[:] + EIRP[-1:] * 3
data3 = data3[:1] * 3 + data3[:] + data3[-1:] * 3
data15 = data15[:1] * 3 + data15[:] + data15[-1:] * 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
li = [EIRP,data3,data15]
ws = 3
for i in range(ws):
    for j in li:
        j.insert(0, j[0])
        j.append(j[-1])
```

I hope that this is what you want